# What to do when a NOAA ERDDAP dataset is not found?

Tags: r, noaa, ropensci, rnoaa

I'm trying to download some gridded ERDDAP data using the `rnoaa` package in R. While the data retrieval works perfectly for some datasets, I'm having some problems getting the data for some datasets in particular. For example when I run:

```
library (rnoaa)
ds.info <- erddap_info ("noaa_pfeg_95de_54ab_a60a")
erddap_grid (ds.info, 
             time = c("2005-01-01", "2015-01-01"), 
             altitude = c (0,0), 
             latitude = c (3.25, 3.75), 
             longitude = c (72.5, 73.25), 
             fields = "all")
```

I get the following error:

```
`Error: (404) - Resource not found: /erddap/griddap/ncdcOwDly.csv (Currently unknown datasetID=ncdcOwDly)`.
```

The error is not really consistent because it works **sometimes** when I try different time-spans. But I get it pretty much every single time I try to download data from the datasets `noaa_pfeg_95de_54ab_a60a`, `noaa_pfeg_1a4b_0c2a_2365` and some others by [NOAA-NCDC](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/rsad/air-sea/seawinds.html).

Because `erddap_grid` works for some datasets but not for others, I'm inclined to think it's not a bug. Maybe it is a problem of the ERDDAP server?, or maybe something to do with my API key? Is there a way around it?

---

Update -  2015-01-10: It seems it is a server's problem. When trying to download the data using the address generated by the web interface (see below) I get the same error. I guess I'll just have to wait until "they" fix the problem with the database.

```
http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/ncdcOw6hr.csv?u[(2006-01-01):1:(2015-01-09T18:00:00Z)][(10.0):1:(10.0)][(3.25):1:(3.75)][(72.5):1:(73.25)],v[(2006-01-01):1:(2015-01-09T18:00:00Z)][(10.0):1:(10.0)][(3.25):1:(3.75)][(72.5):1:(73.25)]
```

Comment: Ill take a deeper look soon...but yeah, seems like a problem on the serve end of things, nice thinking digging into the request itself

Comment: i would ask the erddap folks why some particular queries don't work, not sure why that's happening. I'll fix that bug I found so at least when you get that error on the server side it will be more clear hopefully

Answer (score 0):

ERDDAP servers often become overloaded and 404 on some requests. These are public-facing servers that do heavy data lifting, after all.

So the answer here is to try again after waiting some time (please wait a while to be nice to the ERDDAP administrators), and contact the server administrator to be sure that your IP address has not been blacklisted for performing too many requests.